# Matching all substrings inside parentheses but those starting with blacklisted word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In PHP, using `preg_replace`, how do I write a regular expression so that any phrase, except "The," in parenthesis & preceded by a space is deleted. E.g.,

```
Concordia University (Anything But The) => Concordia University
American University (The) => American University (The)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does `preg_replace` support negative lookaheads?  If so you can do something like this...

`\((?!The\)).*?\)`

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks! I also added "UCSD" to the excluded words: `preg_replace('/ \((?!(The|UCSD)\)).*?\)/', '', $subject)` See the [PHP Documentation on `preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more info.