# How to use regex to delete everything except some words?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression: match all words except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463348/regular-expression-match-all-words-except)

I need your help for using Regex in PHP to negate a selection. So I have a string like this :
"Hello my name is tom"

What I need to do is to delete everything from this string witch is not "tom" or "jack" or "alex" so I tried :

```
$MyString = "Hello my name is tom"
print_r(preg_replace('#^tom|^jack|^alex#i', '', $MyString));
```

But it's not working...

Can you help me with that ?
Thanks

Comment: It should be easier to build a new string from matches of the things you actually want.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, and the answer shown here is much more helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to delete everything except *something*, may be it's better done the other way around: capture the *something* only? For example...

```
$testString = 'Hello my name is tom or jack';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\b(tom|jack|alex)\b/i', $testString, $matches);
$result = implode('', $matches[0]);
echo $result; // tomjack
```

What you've tried to do is use a character class syntax ([`^s]` will match any character but s). But this doesn't work with series of characters, there's no such thing as 'word class'. )

Comment: Thanks for your reply but why do you use $result = implode('', $matches[0]); at the end ? $matches [0] is not an array ?

I saw an other answer that explain to use '#.*(tom|jack|alex).*#i' but you think it's better to use preg_match instead ? I don't realy understand why

Comment: $matches[0] is an array actually, hence the implode' call. The other answer will happily remove all the toms/jacks/alexes duplicates in the original string, so I consider my solution a slightly superior to it. )

Comment: Took me a while to understand that this is no replace but plucking out the needed names into a new array, and then implode that new array into a string with the names. Clever.

Answer (score 0):

regex:

```
\b(?!tom|jack|alex)[^\s]+\b
```

Comment: If he did that, he'd just replace any tom/jack/alex with nothing. He wants to do the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything that is **not** "tom" or "jack" or "alex" you can use the following:

```
$MyString = "Hello my name is jack";
print_r(preg_replace('#.*(tom|jack|alex)#i', '$1', $MyString));
```

This replaces the whole string with just the matched name.

Comment: I tried it and it work better with this regex'#.*(tom|jack|alex).*#i' because without the .* at the end it doesn't destroy the end of the string after the match

Comment: And what will happen with 'My name is tom, and I am not jack' string? )

Comment: I don't see the problem with the * it means the character can be use 0 or more times no ?, but you still helped me ;-)

Comment: It won't remove unwanted string at the end part

Answer (score 0):

You could match what you want and then reconstruct the string:

```
$s = 'hello my name is tom, jack and alex';

if (preg_match_all('/(?:tom|jack|alex)/', $s, $matches)) {
print_r($matches);
        $s = join('', $matches[0]);
} else {
        $s = '';
}

echo $s;
```

Output:

```
tomjackalex
```