# PHP function to generate clean URL - apostrophes

Tags: php, clean-urls, apostrophe

I want to create clean URLs for my database site and I've decided that the best way is to create a field in which to store the URLs for their respective entries.

I am using the GenerateUrl function (found [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)) to create a clean URL from the source name:-

```
function GenerateUrl ($s) {

    // Convert accented characters, and remove parentheses and apostrophes
    $from = explode (',', "ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u,(,),[,],'");
    $to   = explode (',', 'c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,,,,,,');

    // Do the replacements, and convert all other non-alphanumeric characters to spaces
    $s = preg_replace ('~[^\w\d]+~', '-', str_replace ($from, $to, trim ($s)));

    // Remove a - at the beginning or end and make lowercase
    return strtolower (preg_replace ('/^-/', '', preg_replace ('/-$/', '', $s)));
}
```

It works great for the most part, although I am having problems with apostrophes.

Used as quotation marks (i.e. only touching another character on one side) they work fine:-
'Eiffel Tower (Paris)' becomes the URL: `eiffel-tower-paris`

But used as actual apostrophes (i.e. being sandwiched between two characters), not so well:-
St Paul's Cathedral (London) becomes the URL: `st-paul-s-cathedral-london`

I'm using PHP 5.4.3 and have code to undo the modifications of magic quotes (should this be the cause of the problem).

Any advice on solving this greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

---

Yes, desired URL would be: `st-pauls-cathedral-london`

I've just figured out the original function code I gave DOES work (apostrophes are replaced with nothing at the end of the $from and $to rows respectively).

However, it only seems to works if I apply the function to the name live on the page, i.e.

```
<?php echo generateurl($attraction['attraction_name']); ?>
```

But what I am currently doing is applying the function within the index.php file when data is entered into the website.  I *suspect* the problem is coming from the fact that I am applying the function to a value which has already had the below function applied to it (to deal with magic quotes):-

```
$attraction_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['attraction_name']);
$attraction_url = generateurl($attraction_name);
```

I reckon I've got to shift some coding around to generate the URL from the attraction_name before it is affected by mysqli_real_escape_string.  I'll let you know how I get on...

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  You're satisfied with eiffel-tower-paris because you have a line that removes leading and trailing `-` characters, your `\`` get converted too in this situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it turns out that 'mysqli_real_escape_string' was the cause of the problem.  A bit of reordering of the code seems to have sorted it:-

```
$attraction_url = generateurl($_POST['attraction_name']);
$attraction_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['attraction_name']);
```

Thanks!

Andy

---

How to remove 'the', 'a', and 'an' from start of any URL:-

Replace the bottom line of the above GenerateUrl function code with:-

```
return strtolower (preg_replace ('/^-/', '', preg_replace ('/-$/', '', preg_replace ('/\b(^the|^a|^an)\b/i', '', $s))));
```

Useful advice on this subject from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049252/how-to-use-regex-to-delete-everything-except-some-words).

And good article on using \b for word boundaries in regular expressions from [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 3):

If `st-paul-s-cathedral-london` isn't right, then I assume you wanted `st-pauls-cathedral-london`? In that case, I think it's best to just remove all apostrophes from the string altogether. If it's inbetween letters, it will be removed completely, so `paul's` becomes `pauls`, but if there's another character, then that character will become a dash anyway, so the apostroph still isn't needed.

I would change the last line, like shown below. It replaces the `'` with nothing, and uses a more simple `trim` to remove the leading and trailing dash. No regular expressions needed and the code is shorter and more clear.

```
return trim(str_replace("'", '', strtolower($s)), '-');
```

Comment: New info in original post.  Thanks for help so far.

Comment: Yeah, mysqli_real_escape_string escapes some special characters. I think it replaces `'` with `\'`, so the apastroph may be removed from your string, but the `\` is still translated to a dash. You should call `mysqli_real_escape_string` at the very end. Or actually you shouldn't call it at all, because using *prepared statements* (using PDO or mysqli) is a better solution, but that's a completely different story altogether.

Comment: I now want to remove the word 'The' (or 'the') from the start of any URLs that I create (and 'A' and 'An' as well once I've got that working).  Surely it should be a simple change made to the bottom line of the function (see below), but it does not appear to be working - any ideas?

`return strtolower (preg_replace ('/^-/', '', preg_replace ('/-$/', '', preg_replace ('/^the /i', '', $s))));`

Comment: Maybe it's best to close this question and start a new one for this new case. It will have more visibility to other users, and it's better to paste code in a question and answer than in comments underneath another answer.

Comment: Have found the answer I needed so have added it below in my last post.  Still new to the site but in future will open up new question separately as suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: SO usually doesn't work by taking someone's answer and the discussion that follows, more or less paste it in your own answer and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add another regexp to remove apostrophes.

```
$s = str_replace ($from, $to, trim ($s));
$s = preg_replace("~'~", '', $s);
$s = preg_replace ('~[^\w\d]+~', '-', $s);
```